# Return a value from Google maps addListener () function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, handler

I am using the Google Maps Javscript API :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      }

      // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
      markers = [];
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var image = {
          url: places[0].icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for the closest result
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          draggable : true,
          title: places[0].name,
          position: places[0].geometry.location
        });

        $('#inputLocalisation').val(places[0].geometry.location);
        markers.push(marker);


        bounds.extend(places[0].geometry.location);

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });
```

This handler is triggered when the user searches a location. It creates a marker on the closest result.

I would like to return the marker to use it later in an other handler :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function() {
        $('#inputLocalisation').val(marker.getPosition());
    });
```

This one is triggered when the marker is dragged, but I need the marker object. How can I access the previously created marker?

Answer (score 1):

So you should be adding that event listener at the same time as you're creating the marker I assume?

In the event listener function you can refer to it using the keyword `this`.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      draggable : true,
      title: places[0].name,
      position: places[0].geometry.location
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function() {
    $('#inputLocalisation').val(this.getPosition());
});
```